# rendered font in IE7 width is bigger than in other borwsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, fonts

Rendered font in IE7 width is bigger than in other borwsers ( Top image part is IE9, bottom part is Firefox ):

[image: Snapshot]

The HTML:

```
            <div id="header_tools">
                <a href="#">Support</a> | <a href="#">FAQs</a> | <a href="#">Sitemap</a> | <a href="#">Help</a>
            </div>
```

and CSS

```
    div#header_tools {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight:  normal;
        color: #918e8e;
        float: left;
    }

    div#header_tools {
        position: relative;
        top: 7px;
        left: 680px;
    }

    div#header_tools  a {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #918e8e;
    }
```

Anybody knows why is it going and how to fix it ?

Comment: have you tried setting your padding on div#header_tools  a to 0

Comment: Yes. This doesn't make sence, because div#header_tools inherirs padding: 0px

Comment: Does the problem occur when you test with the exact code you posted and no extras? The screenshots are from a different setup. And the code is so simple that the odds are that the problem is elsewhere. It may also matter what the font is, and this is not specified in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to concern the word-spacing (this is a CSS attribute too). The simplest probably is to use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces.

(It seems that there is a difference in font anti-aliasing/hinting too.)
Sorry, I think the font rendering is causing a slight difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting your link padding to 0 and changing your spaces to `&nbsp;` or not using spaces at all instead using padding.

```
div#header_tools  a {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #918e8e;
         padding:0;
    }
```